# jq slow to join() medium size array

Tags: json, jq, processing-efficiency

I am trying to join() a relatively big array (20k elements) of objects with a character ('\n' in this particular case). I have a few operation upfront which solve in about 8 seconds (acceptable) but when I try to '| join("\n")' at the end the runtime jump to 3+ minutes.

Is there any reason for the join() to be that slow ? Is there another way of having the same output without join() ?

I am currently using jq-1.5 (latest stable)

Here is the JQ file

json2csv.jq

```
def json2csv:
    def tonull: if . == "null" then null else . end;
    (.[0] | keys) as $headers |
    [(
        $headers | join("\t")
    ), (
        [ .[] as $row | [ $headers[] as $h | $row[$h] | tostring | tonull ] | join("\t") ] | join("\n")
    )] | join("\n")
;

json2csv
```

Considering:

```sh
$ jq 'length' test.json 
23717
```

With the script is I want it (and put above)

```sh
$ time jq -rf json2csv.jq test.json > test.csv

real    3m46.721s
user    1m48.660s
sys     1m57.698s
```

With the same script, removing the join("\n")

```sh
$ time jq -rf json2csv.jq test.json > test.csv

real    0m8.564s
user    0m8.301s
sys     0m0.242s
```

(note: I remove the second join because else JQ cannot aggregate an array and a string, which make sense (but that's only on an array of 2 elements anyways, so the second join isn't the problem))

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use join at all. Rather than thinking of converting the whole file to a single string, think of it as converting each row to strings. The way jq outputs streams of results will give you the desired result in the end (assuming you take the raw output).

try something more like this.

```
def json2csv:
    def tonull: if . == "null" then null else . end;
    (.[0] | keys) as $headers
    # output headers followed by rows of values as arrays
     |  (
            $headers
        ),
        (
            .[] | [ .[$headers[]] | tostring | tonull ]
        )
    # convert the arrays to tab separated values strings
     |  @tsv
     ;
```

Comment: I cannot use this as the @tsv jq command is quite restrictive with what is a "value", sadly

Comment: If you feel that `@tsv` will not work for you, you may still use `join("\t")` as you have already done. Just know that you will have to deal with escaping the values yourself as needed. The point here is that you're only generating strings for each of the rows, rather than the entire final result.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it I remembered that jq automatically display carriage return ('\n') if you scan an array (.[]), which mean that in this particular case I can just do this:

```
def json2csv:
    def tonull: if . == "null" then null else . end;
    (.[0] | keys) as $headers |
    [(
        $headers | join("\t")
    ), (
        [ .[] as $row | [ $headers[] as $h | $row[$h] | tostring | tonull ] | join("\t") ] | .[]
    )] | .[]
;

json2csv
```

And this solved my problem

```sh
time jq -rf json2csv.jq test.json > test.csv

real    0m6.725s
user    0m6.454s
sys     0m0.245s
```

I'm leaving the question up as if I had wanted to use any other character than '\n' this wouldn't have solved the issue.

Comment: Why don't you just pass arrays to `@tsv`?

Answer (score 0):

When producing output such as CSV or TSV, the idea is to stream the data as much as possible.  The last thing you want to do is run `join` on an array containing all the data. If you did want to use a delimiter other than `\n`, you'd add it to each item in the stream, and then use the -j command-line option.

Also, I think your diagnosis is probably not quite right as joining an array with a large number of small strings is quite fast.  Below are timings comparing joining an array with two strings and one with 100,000 strings.  In case you're wondering, my machine is rather slow.

```
./join.sh 2
3
real         0.03
user         0.02
sys          0.00
   1896448  maximum resident set size

$ ./join.sh 100000
588889
real         2.20
user         2.05
sys          0.13
  21188608  maximum resident set size


$cat join.sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/time -lp jq -n --argjson n "$1" '[range(0;$n)|tostring]|join(".")|length'
```

---

The above runs used jq 1.6, but using jq 1.5 produces very similar results.

On the other hand, joining a large number (20,000) of very long strings (1K) is noticeably slow, so evidently the current jq implementation is not designed for such operations.

Comment: I think you're exactly right, my string are several K long...
What does the -j option do? It doesn't exist on jq 1.5

Comment: `jq-1.5 --help` does not advertise it but version 1.5 does support it.  The -j option simply suppresses the newlines that are normally supplied between JSON entities.  See the jq manual.